# MVC 3 Custom/Http error pages not shown for View exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have custom/http errors set up in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that will be shown on errors. My `Web.Config`'s `httpErrors` section looks like this:

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="400" />
        <remove statusCode="403" />
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <remove statusCode="408" />
        <remove statusCode="500" />
        <remove statusCode="503" />
        <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/BadRequest" />
        <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Forbidden" />
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
        <error statusCode="408" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Timeout" />
        <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/InternalServerError" />
        <error statusCode="503" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/ServiceUnavailable" />
    </httpErrors>
```

I haven't set the `customerErrors` setting as this doesn't work well with MVC & IIS 7.5.

All works fine, when an exception occurs in code.

However, when an exception is thrown in a view - it tries to show the default `~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml` which I don't have.

The view that might throw an error could be this:

```
@Html.Partial("TemplateSection", Model.PreContent)
```

And imagine `PreContent` is null, and the `TemplateSection` view will fail when displaying values by doing this: `@Model.Name`